# statistics; significance between two groups

Tags: statistics

I'm testing two groups (guilty and innocent). Both contain 40 values. I would like to know which values of the guilty group are significantly greater than those of the innocent group.
I'm not so much interested whether there is a significant difference between the two groups in general (already did that: one way anova).

My goal is to plot two lines in a graph. Then highlight where the guilty group scores significantly higher than the innocent group.

Thank you in advance,
F

Answer (score 0):

So, statistics doesn't really work like that. What you're doing by comparing the two groups is comparing their means and their standard deviations. Specifically does one group, the test group, have values that are different from some control group given a particular sample size and probability. Typically the probability is 95%. What this means is, if these two groups are actually not different at all, what are the chances I would see values this different from one another. If the chance of seeing that difference is less than 5%, it is considered significant. The reason one group is more significant is not because of select few people, but because the values of Group A are different from the values of Group B (the means).

You could take all 80 entries, and sort from highest to lowest, and then take the top half, but that would completely destroy any relevance to a test group and a control group, and thus wouldn't actually test anything.

Comment: first of all i'd like to thank you for your quick reply.

Now, imagine you have two teams ( girls vs boys) competing each other in a sportsgame (basketball?). they always end up with an equal score, none of both ever wins. Now imagine that i take one of the girls out of the group (or replace her) and the girls start losing badly... This means that this girl was by far the best player of her team, contributing significantly.

Now back to my scenario; ive got two groups with about equal scores. yet some scores of 1 group reach much higher outcomes.

Comment: In a graph it is obvious which ones. i wich i could highlight these 'significant'differences.

Statistics doesn't really work like this?

Comment: Let me try to illicit the answer from you. In your graph where this is obvious, what is the dimension on the X axis? What are you showing on the Y axis?

Comment: X: time in seconds
Y: Skin conductance scores

Hypothesis: group A will show higher Skin conductance scores when a question is asked 

(note: question is asked at 15th second. And my graph shows that indeed guilty individuals show much higher skin conductance levels around the 15. th second.)

Comment: So the way this works is, take all the innocent people and average their scores at 15 seconds. Take all the guilty people and average their scores. To test if there is a difference in skin conductance between your two groups you have to use everyone. This larger sample size helps you filter out noise, and lets to you detect the effect (guilty or innocent) that you are looking for. Noise in this case would be, what if someone just did exercise before your study and had an abnormally high skin conductance. Their high SC isn't from the guilt effect but because of the exercise they did.

Comment: An important contributing factor of performing a t-test is that it takes into account the variance. Imagine a basketball team, some days they score 10 points, other games they score 200. They play against another team who scores the same way and beat them by 1 point, 50 to 51. Are they significantly better? Well no, probably not, because the variance in their scores are so high. Just based on if they had a good day or not, their points change by 190.  Maybe they had a good day that day.